How to prove the machine learning voting model is no worse than single model?
Suppose there are $N$ binary classifiers, $N$ is odd, each with an error rate of $e$, so $e \in [0, 0.5]$.
so I need prove:
$$P(X \ge \lceil N/2 \rceil) = \sum_{k= \lceil N/2 \rceil}^N\binom{N}{k} e^k (1-e)^{N-k} \le e$$
let $F(k,N,p)=\sum_{i= \lceil k \rceil}^N\binom{N}{i} p^i (1-p)^{N-k}$
so $F(k,N,0)=0$, $F(k, N, 0.5)=0.5$;
If I can prove that F is a convex function in the interval [0, 0.5], then the original conjecture can be proven.
based on this post Monotonicity of the CDF of a Binomial Distribution:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F(k, n, p)}{\partial p} &= \frac{1}{p(1-p)} \cdot \bigg( E[X( \lceil k \rceil)] - np \bigg)\cdot F(k, N, p) > 0
\end{align*}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial ^2 F(k, n, p)}{\partial p^2} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial p} \Bigg(\frac{1}{p(1-p)} \cdot \big( E[X( \lceil k \rceil)] - np \big)\cdot F(k, N, p) - 1 \Bigg)\\
&= \big( E[X( \lceil k \rceil)] - np \big)\cdot F(k, N, p) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\bigg(\frac{1}{p(1-p)}\bigg) + \frac{1}{p(1-p)}\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial p}\Bigg(E[X( \lceil k \rceil)] - np \big)\cdot F(k, N, p) \Bigg) \\
&=( E[X( \lceil k \rceil)] - np \big)\cdot F(k, N, p) \cdot \frac{2p-1}{p^2(1-p)^2}+\frac{1}{p(1-p)}\cdot\Bigg(F(k, N, p)\cdot \bigg(\frac{\partial (E[X( \lceil k \rceil)])}{\partial p}-n\bigg) +(E[X( \lceil k \rceil)]-np)^2\cdot\frac{1}{p(1-p)}\cdot(F(k, N, p)\Bigg)
\end{align*}
$$
for $\frac{\partial (E[X( \lceil k \rceil)])}{\partial p}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial (E[X( \lceil k \rceil)])}{\partial p}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\bigg(\sum_{i= \lceil k \rceil}^{N} i \cdot \frac{\binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}}{F(k, N, p)}\bigg)\\
&=\sum_{i= \lceil k \rceil}^{N} i\binom{n}{i}\cdot\frac{ p^{i-1} (1-p)^{n-i-1} ( i - np -  E[X( \lceil k \rceil)] + np )}{F(k, N, p)}\\
&=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}\bigg(\sum_{i= \lceil k \rceil}^{N}\frac{i^2\binom{n}{i}p^i (1-p)^{n-i}}{F(k, N, p)}-\sum_{i= \lceil k \rceil}^{N}\frac{i\binom{n}{i}p^i (1-p)^{n-i}E[X( \lceil k \rceil)]}{F(k, N, p)}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}(E[X( \lceil k \rceil)^2]-E[X( \lceil k \rceil)]^2)\\
&=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}\cdot D[X( \lceil k \rceil)]
\end{align*}
$$
so:
$$
\frac{\partial ^2 F(k, n, p)}{\partial p^2} 
=\frac{F(k, n, p)}{p^2(1-p)^2}\bigg(\big(E[X( \lceil k \rceil)] - np \big)(2p-1) + D[X( \lceil k \rceil)] - np(1-p) + (E[X( \lceil k \rceil)]-np)^2\bigg)
$$
finally, I should prove $p\in[0, 0.5]$ and $k=(N+1)/2$:
$(E-np)(2p-1)+D-np(1-p)+(E-np)^2 > 0$
I cannot prove it, but through code simulation, the conclusion seems to be correct.
